# How to getet url query string in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to get url query string that comes back from the security API, so my URL looks like this `www.mysite.com/profile#code=xxxx&id_token=xxx` I'd like to get the values of `code and id_token`.

I tried using activatedRoute in my `ngOnInit()` but params is `undefined`. Can someone shed a light if this is the right way? I have created a function but its not an angular way of getting the URL query string.

```
this.routeParam.queryParams
  .subscribe(params => {
    let code = params['id_token'];
    console.log('code val >> ', code);
  })
```

My attempt which works but I'd like to do it in angular way.

```
getURLVars(key) {
var vars = [], hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('#') + 1).split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
  hash = hashes[i].split('=');
  vars.push(hash[0]);
  vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
return vars[key];
}
```

Comment: Did you try getting it from [fragments](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters)?

Comment: But that'd give me the whole query string? can I specifically say `param['code']`? so it'd give me only the value I need.

Comment: you have to build your URL in a different way so that instead of `#` it has `?` , then you would be able to get it as query params, Cheers!!

Comment: yeah except that the url is coming back from the API, all I have is like `'/profile&response_type=code token&id_token`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Using snapshot you can get the query string from URL.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    let code = this.router.snapshot.queryParams['id_token'];
 }
```